# Accessing Google cloud VM applications through external IP

Tags: networking, cloud, virtual-machine, google-cloud-platform

I have Google Cloud instance (RHEL 6.7 and I have an application working on HTTPS protocol on port 10614). This is perfectly working when I am using the internal IP `https://10.125.0.7:10614/home`.

I have an external IP with which I am connecting to this machine which is `104.118.81.121`.

So i would like to expose my application to the internet using this IP address. Could you please help, how should I be doing the mapping for this?

I have already created the firewall rule for this, but it is not working.

Comment: The phrase "but it is not working" is rather... broad. Please tell us a) what you have done so far, b) what the expected behaviour should be, and c) what the actual observed behaviour is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open port 10614 in your Google Cloud Console firewall. You can use the following link: https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/list?project=your-project-id. Just replace your-project-id with your project id.